# liveCDs detecting wrong video card

Tags: hardware, video, livecd

I just replaced my video / graphics card with a new model, the AMD firepro m6100. None of my ubuntu 13.10 based liveCDs are able to run correctly (manually running startx from tty1 fails, so that's probably part of it). I suspect the root of the problem is that Dell (supposedly) changes the hardware ID for their hardware.

I need to find a way around this so I can not only run a live environment but also repair my broken GRUB install, and eventually get my system running with the new video card.

lspci - in the live environment - spits out the following:

```
1:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ... [AMD/ATI] Saturn XT [Radeon HD 8950M] (prog-if 00 [VGA Controlle...
Subsystem: Dell Device 04a4
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
I/O ports at 7000 [size=256]
Memory at e4100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
Expansion ROM at e4140000 [disabled] [size=128K]
...
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010
...
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with kernel 3.13 (found in *buntu 14.04).

Additionally, the experimental binary catalyst driver 14.10.2 (and up?) works with the firepro m6100.